# Passing an argument in a different way in a self-made environment

Tags: tables

I want to pass an argument to a self-made tabular environment in the following format:

```
\begin{customTabular}{|c|c|}{'@'}
```

...such that the second argument (here `'@'`, WITHIN PARANTHESIS) is treated as a column separator symbol by the LaTeX document. How this can be done? Please suggest the changes/modifications in the code attached.

The code for `customTabular` environment is as follows (here, `mytabular` is similar to `customTabular`):

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment {mytabular} { O{\,} }
  {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \&
    \char_set_catcode_alignment:n {`#1}
    \begin{tabular}
  }
  {
    \end{tabular}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for wanting the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the argument an optional group (or perhaps mandatory), and to arrange to strip any quote marks before using as a number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment {mytabular} { O{c} m G{','} }
  {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N &
    \char_set_catcode_alignment:n { \__mytab_test:n {#3} }
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}
  }
  {
    \end{tabular}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__mytab_test:n #1 { \__mytab_test:w #1 ' #1 '' \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__mytab_test:w #1 ' #2 ' #3 \q_stop { `#2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{mytabular}{cc}{'@'}
  a @ b\\
  c @ d
\end{mytabular}

\begin{mytabular}{cc}{@}
  a @ b\\
  c @ d
\end{mytabular}
\end{document}
```

The trick in removing `'` tokens is that TeX is greedy in a match. So with

```
#1 ' #2 ' #3
```

any input containing a leading `'` will have an empty `#1`, the 'argument' in `#2` and rubbish left in `#3`. If there was no leading `'`, then `#1` will be the same as `#2` due to the set up macro, which supplies the input both with and without additional `'` tokens.

Comment: Thank You @Joseph. The answer really worked, but the syntax used is quite complicated and out of my current understanding of LaTeX. But, still the answer was helpful and it worked as the way I required. Please provide a simpler solution to the problem if possible.Thank You for solving my question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require the quotes, your code works, provided you use *square brackets* for the argument. It's better style to also add the mandatory argument for the columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment {mytabular} { O{\,} m }
  {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \&
    \char_set_catcode_alignment:n {`#1}
    \begin{tabular}{#2}
  }
  {
    \end{tabular}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{mytabular}[@]{cc}
  a @ b\\
  c @ d
\end{mytabular}

\begin{mytabular}{cc}
  a , b\\
  c , d
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a syntax such as `\begin{mytabular}{cc}[@]`, just exchange the arguments

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment {mytabular} { m O{\,} }
  {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \&
    \char_set_catcode_alignment:n {`#2}
    \begin{tabular}{#1}
  }
  {
    \end{tabular}
  }
```

Comment: Thank You for your contribution but I do want the use of quotes in the argument passing method in the environment.

Comment: @Naman What are they for?

Comment: Nothing much, rather, only a new way of trying the old stuff...